# función appendChildren

Tags: javascript, html

La función appendChildren debe añadir un nuevo hijo div

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function appendChildren(decorateDivFunction){
        var allDivs = document.getElementsByTagName("div");

        for (var i = 0; i < allDivs.length; i++){
            var newDiv = document.createElement("div");
            decorateDivFunction(newDiv);
            allDivs[i].appendChildren(newDiv);
        }
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define el final del for en una variable separada, antes del bloque for

```
var allDivs = document.getElementsByTagName("div");

var end = allDivs.length;

for (var i = 0; i < end; i++){
    var newDiv = document.createElement("div");
    decorateDivFunction(newDiv);
    allDivs[i].appendChildren(newDiv);
}
```